# Displaying latest entries in Umbraco

Tags: c#, xslt, umbraco

I'm new to Xslt and Umbraco.

I'm trying to fetch the latest, say for example 4, entries from my umbraco database and display them on the homepage. There is an image, title, date, and body that are entered in content tab, in a page, which should be assosiated with eachother.

Using Xslt, how do I go about firstly, associating the image, title, date, and body text with eachother. And Secondly, displaying the latest descending entries by date?

Comment: What does the input XML look like?  What kind  of XML output do you want?

Comment: @JLRishe Have you had any experience with Umbraco?

Comment: I have not, but I have a lot of experience with XSLT, and I think you'll find a lot more experienced XSLT users than Umbraco users here. If your question is Umbraco specific, that's fine, but if it's possible to do so, you may get better results by splitting your Umbraco question and your XSLT question into separate questions, so that people with expertise in either topic can focus their efforts better. It's possisble this question could be reduced to a question about what kind of result markup you need, and a separate question about how to obtain that with XSLT, but I can't say that for sure.

Comment: @JLRishe The problem is that you don;t really see the XML in Umbraco.

Comment: I see.  Well there do seem to be a fair number of people asking Umbraco questions here.  Hopefully someone can help. :)

Comment: OP / @JLRiche you will find the xml that Umbraco is using in the /App_Data/umbraco.config file

Answer (score 0):

You create a doc type (this contains the metadata of the nodes like image, title, body, date); then create a template which contains the markup interspersed with the content placeholders (the umbraco:item or umbraco:macro bits).

Add a macro that contains your xslt to show the last four items; and put that macro in the template.

Then create some content node based on this doc type/template (in many cases the doc type to template ratio is 1:1).

In those content nodes you can then specify the contents of those fields you set up in the doc type.

I don't do any xslt any more - I only use razor in macros - but your macro would look something like:

```
  <xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/descendant-or-self::node [@nodeTypeAlias='itemType']">
    <xsl:sort select="data[@alias='createdDate']" order="descending" />
    <xsl:if test="position() &lt;= 4">
      <xsl:value-of select="@title" />
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
```